# What is a good reason for separating intelligence and dao layers in a microservice?

Tags: dao, microservices

I am having a long-term debate with my architect about architecture choices. The entreprise where I work in is migrating from a monolithic architecture to a microservices one.

The debate is located on the good approach for handling database access. One of us is standing there is no need for separating DAO and service (database access are directly handled by the service class), and the other stands for the contrary.

We are discussing about it for days, and I can't find good reason for convincing him, and he cannot either convince me.

The question is actually really simple: in an atomic REST microservice (a microservice handling only one REST method), should we have a separate DAO class or not? Which arguments could you give for separating, or keeping everything together?

This is a OOP oriented project (Java), if it matters.

Edit: This quest has been reposted on [softwareengineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/334848/what-is-a-good-reason-for-separating-intelligence-and-dao-layers-in-a-microservi/334873#334873)

Comment: If anything, this is a question for the folks over at http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com; though do take a tour and familiarize yourself with what kind of question they like over there. It's too opinion based for SO.

Comment: Consider that your implementation will be better if it's done based in SOLID principle.

Comment: With your understanding of the domain of the microservice, do you ever see there being more endpoints and functionality being added to this microservice in the near future?

Comment: This is a general question, so we can suppose the answernwould be "yes".